# Jquery function changing the dropdown value from one to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dropdown values. if i select one **dropdown(CandidateFunctions)** values, it will populate the another **dropdown(PreferredFunctions)**. This is working good only. but when i select the **CandidateFunctions** in the second time it is not changing the value..

**My code in jquery is**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                   $("#CandidateFunctions").change(function () {
                       if ($("#PreferredFunctions").val() == "" || $("#PreferredFunctions").val() == null) {
                           $("#PreferredFunctions").val($("#CandidateFunctions").val());
                       }
                   });
                });
```

how to populate the values even second time also? please help me...

Comment: Because after the first change it's no longer null or an empty string

Comment: Remove the if or add another condition

Comment: how will change the condition. i put another condition like != null . but still it is not changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like The code below should help u:

```
$("#dropdwon1").change(function(){
    $("#dropdwon2").val($(this).val());
});
```

working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/xkT3U/

Answer (score 0):

Better way is use [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and bind event on document not on selector, and let the framework to find the target and invoke function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on("change","#CandidateFunctions",function () {
      if ($("#PreferredFunctions").val() == "" || $("#PreferredFunctions").val() == null) {
            $("#PreferredFunctions").val($("#CandidateFunctions").val());
        }
     });
  });
```